# Mapping RDDs using an object's member function

Tags: python, apache-spark, keras, pyspark

I would like to map a function `foo(x, my_object)` to an RDD `rdd`

```
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: foo(x, my_object))
```

where `foo` is defined as

```
def foo(x, some_object):

    return [x, some_object.member_function(x)]
```

In other words, the mapping applies a member function of the passed object. (In my particular case, the `member_function()` is essentially a call to a Keras `predict()` function.)

The problem is that I get the error `PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects`. Apparently, Spark has a problem handling certain objects.

What is the best way to do this?

PS: I'm not dead-set on using RDDs, actually I would have preferred working with DataFrames.

**EDIT**: Unlike the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187570/how-to-pass-deep-learning-model-data-to-map-function-in-spark) proposed as a duplicate, this problem isn't specific to deep learning. Besides, I am looking for a minimum working example, which the proposed duplicate isn't (references to AWS' S3, etc.). Finally, there is no explanation as to why `mapPartitions()` is the solution. I just want a way to perform a mapping and pass an object. Why can't that work? This has supposedly something to do with Spark's serialization mechanisms, but I'd like to know what the (elegant) workarounds could be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass deep learning model data to map function in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187570/how-to-pass-deep-learning-model-data-to-map-function-in-spark)

Comment: @user10465355 Although the low-level problem might be the same, my problem isn't specific to deep learning. (That example you linked to is too complex. I'm looking for a solution to the minimum working example I presented in the OP.)